# Get AutoHotKey to do keyboard shortcut when mouse in certain position

Tags: autohotkey

I'm a complete newbie idiot trying to write an AutoHotKey script that does a keyboard shortcut (in this case, windows button + t) when my mouse is in a certain position on screen (in this case, below 1070 pixels). This is what I have wrote put I don't think it actually does anything.

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
Check:
MouseGetPos, yy
if (yy < 1070) {
    Send {LWin down}t{LWin up}
Return
}
```

The syntax is probably way off from what AutoHotKey is actually supposed to look like but after reading some forum posts I still can't tell what I did wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Your code does the following:  When autohotkey starts and the mouse cursor is within the 1070 pixels of the left margin, simulate pressing Window+T. Is that really what you wanted?  Some red flags in your code include 1) using `yy` to store an x-coordinate,  2) a label that is never used (`Check:`), 3) code is not event driven (it only runs when autohotkey is started or reloaded), 4)  misleading indention that doesn't match the bracketed code block (`Return`)

Answer (score 1):

This code does *literally* what you asked for

```
Loop {
    MouseGetPos, x, y
    if (y < 1070){
        Send {LWin down}t{LWin up}
    }
    Sleep 10 ; Avoid excessive CPU usage
}
```

However, whilst y is < 1070, it would *constantly* send the key combo.
I guess you only want it to send the key combo when the mouse first "enters" the zone.

```
last_pos := 999999  ; Set initial value really high
Loop {
    MouseGetPos, x, y
    if (y < 1070 && last_pos >= 1070){
        Send {LWin down}t{LWin up}
    }
    last_pos := y
    Sleep 10 ; Avoid excessive CPU usage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#t:: ;This will assign the window + t key to do something

{

Click 701,480      ;This clicks to a certain position on the screen. Autoit software can find the coordinates on the screen for you.

Send Hello         ;This will write something in an area like if its on a webpage or something.

Send {Return} 
     {Space}
     {ESC}
     {up}     ;The {} Hold different keystrokes to use- https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Sleep 300     ;This allows you to pause the program, you may need something to finish loading in.



}
```

This is just some background information for you to use for future, using what Clive Galway has said should work for you, if the position you want to do something is set use the Click ....,.... however if it may be at different points use the above answer.